# Missing Android Instant App Statistics on Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-instant-apps

How do I get Android Instant App/Open Statistics to show something on the Google Play Console?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [View app statistics > Android Instant Apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?hl=en&ref_topic=7071935#instant_app)

> Note: For privacy reasons, Google doesn't display instant app data
>   when there are a low number of users.

What it doesn't specifically say is that you need a minimum of 50 data points per day for it to show something. Otherwise, it it just empty.

Comment: My game app is still virtually invisible even after spending thousands to google ads. Thanks tor the 50 figure, I've never gotten close to that.